# при частом обновлении окна консоли с помощью Console.Clear(); не видно текст, есть ли обходной || похожий способ изменить текст в консоли

Tags: c#

в общем такая проблема: когда код часто обновляется не видно того, что выводится в эту консоль как можно изменить текст в ней без task.delay и прочих замедляющих код функций
вот часть кода с проблемой:

```
 //наглядная демонстрация загрузки// //с малыми числами работает плохо (не показывается)//
                long[] loading = new long[4] { increasedvalue, 0, increasedvalue / 100, 0 };
                long lastl1 = 0;
                void loadingillustrtion()
                {
                    
                    char[] loadscreen = ("[__________]").ToCharArray(); ;
                    if (loading[1] != 0 || lastl1 != 0 && lastl1 != loading[1] || loading[3] != 0)
                    {
                        lastl1 = loading[1];

                        long count = loading[1] + 1;
                        int lcount = 1;
                        while (lcount != count)
                        {
                            loadscreen[lcount] = '#';
                            lcount++;
                        }
                    }
                    string releaseload = new string(loadscreen);
                    if (loading[1] != 10)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" + releaseload + loading[3] + "%");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t" + releaseload + " complite!");
                    }
```

Comment: `прочих замедляющих` вы хотите 99999999999999999999999 раз в секунду обновлять текст на экране? Зачем? Что вообще должен делать этот код?

Comment: @aepot не совсем так, моя программа считает некоторое выражение пример: 1 000 000 000 -7 и так до нуля, и тогда загрузка выглядит красиво, но при меньших числах загрузка не успевает обновиться

Comment: А чем вам Thread.Sleep не угодил? Нравится, когда процессор на 100% загружен работой?

Comment: @aepot проблема в том, что те же 100 миллионов - 7 оно просчитывает за 74 - 80 секунд, и это нормальная скорость для вывода загрузки, а про меньшие числа я уже говорил

Comment: Thread.sleep замедляет код, а мне нужна максимальная скорость

Comment: Вывод в консоль ещё больше замедляет код, вы не представляете как. Не хотите, чтобы код замедлялся - не выводите ничего в консоль в цикле.

Comment: Можете записывать в переменную время последнего обновления инфы на экране и пропускать обновления экрана, когда прошло слишком мало времени. У вас тормозит именно сам вывод на экран. Компьютер занят этим выводом и больше ничем.

Comment: @CrazyElf про это я вкусе, но та загрузка которую я сделал (вывод в консоль) не замедляет код, так как она оптимизирована под задачу

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за совет, но проблема в том что вывод становится слишком медленным при малых числах

Comment: Ну не делайте `Console.Clear();`, делайте вместо `Console.WriteLine` -> `Console.Write` и заканчивайте строку `\r`.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо этот совет должен помочь

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, теперь выводит, но при этом вверху и внизу консоли остаются части загрузки их как ни будь возможно убрать?

Comment: спасибо всем, вопрос решён

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот простое решение.

Создал класс, который будет отвечать за отображение прогрессбара.

```cs
public class ConsoleProgressBar
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public ConsoleProgressBar(int left, int top, int length)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Length = length;
    }

    public void ShowProgress(int progress)
    {
        if (progress > Length || progress < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid progress value, must be between 0 and {Length} but actual {progress}.");
        (int left, int top) = Console.GetCursorPosition();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
        Console.Write($"{new string('▓', progress)}{new string('░', Length - progress)}");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
    }
}
```

Написал вот такой вот тест

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Clear();
    string title = "Progress: ";
    Console.WriteLine(title);
    int maxProgress = 40;
    ConsoleProgressBar bar = new ConsoleProgressBar(title.Length, 0, maxProgress);
    long previous = -1;
    long total = 1000000000;
    for (long i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        long progress = i * maxProgress / total;
        if (progress != previous)
        {
            bar.ShowProgress((int)progress);
            previous = progress;
        }
    }
    bar.ShowProgress(maxProgress);
    Console.WriteLine("Complete.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Выглядит это вот так.

```
Progress: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

Никаких пауз, как вы и просили, но перерисовка прогрессбара происходит только тогда, когда это необходимо, то есть его состояние поменялось. В данном конкретном случае вывод в консоль внутри цикла произойдет ровно 40 раз.