# C# Progress bar Console App

Tags: c#, консоль

Приведу для вас дорогой код, для тех, кто не хочет тратить 9 баксов для скачивания спец библиотеки.

```
static void Progressbar() {
            var blackBlock = "█";
            var middleBlock = "▓";
            var ligthBlock = "▒";
            int blockCount = 100;
            
            int start = 11;

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            var posY = Console.CursorTop;
            //var LOADING = " Loading: [{0}{1}{2}]";
           // Console.Write(LOADING);

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            string TEMPLATE = " Loading: [{0}{1}{2}] ";
            Console.SetCursorPosition(start, posY);
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                /* Thread.Sleep(100);
                 TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
                 Console.Write("{0}", new string(' ', ligthBlock.Length));
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, posY);
                 Console.Write("{0}", new string(' ', middleBlock.Length));
                 Thread.Sleep(100);
                 Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
                 Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft - 1, posY);
                 Console.Write("{0}", new string(' ', blackBlock.Length));
                 */

                Thread.Sleep(200);
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200);
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                var output = string.Format(" Loading: [{0}{1}{2}] ",
                    new string(' ', ligthBlock.Length),
                    new string(' ', middleBlock.Length),
                    new string(' ', blackBlock.Length));
                Console.Write(output);
            }

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.Write("] \n");
  }
```

**UPD:**

```
       static void Progressbar() {
            int blockCount = 100;
            int start = 11;
            var posY = Console.CursorTop;

                //               //012345678911
                string template = " Loading: [{0}{1}{2} ] {3}% {4}s";
                Console.WriteLine(template);
                int maxProgress = 50;
                ConsoleProgressBar bar = new ConsoleProgressBar(11, posY, maxProgress);
                long previous = -1;
                long total = 1000000000;
                for (long i = 0; i < total; i++) {
                    long progress = i * maxProgress / total;
                    if (progress != previous) {
                        bar.ShowProgress((int)progress);
                        previous = progress;
                    }
                }

            bar.ShowProgress(maxProgress);
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        }

    }


    public class ConsoleProgressBar {
        public int Left { get; set; }
        public int Top { get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }

        public ConsoleProgressBar(int left, int top, int length) {
            Left = left;
            Top = top;
            Length = length;
        }

        public void ShowProgress(int progress) {
            if (progress > Length || progress < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid progress value, must be between 0 and {Length} but actual {progress}.");

            int start = 0;

            (int left, int top) = Console.GetCursorPosition();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.Write($"{new string('█', progress)}" +
                $"{new string('▓', progress)}" +
                $"{new string('░', Length - progress)}" +
                $"{new string(Convert.ToChar(start++), Length - progress)}" +
$"{new string(Convert.ToChar(Timer.ActiveCount), Length - progress)}");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
}
```

Вот получаю результат:
[image: C# progress bar console App]

Почему не отображается `]` , процент выполнения, время за которое сделано? Да и обратите внимание на то что в половине прогресс бара `█` не дошёл до конца. между скобками во время загрузки тоже можно сделать свободно пространство если надо, то есть в `ShowProgress` указать второй аргумент который будет проверять надо ли пустое пространство между скобками и оно заполняется.

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: `new string(' '` 3 раза разве не выглядит подозрительным? Вот вам бесплатный код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1348617/373567

Comment: @aepot - мой вопрос не дубликат, обрати пожалуйста внимание на то что у тебя в коде есть `Console.Clear()` , он очищает полностью консоль но мне такое не нужно. Мне нужно только лишь получается оду строку удалить или как-то так сделать.

Comment: Уберите `Console.Clear()` все будет работать так как работает, оно же не в цикле чистит экран, верно? А значит на работу самого прогресс-бара никак не влияет. Прочитайте код хотя-бы, весь ответ на вопрос заключается в копировании кода из того ответа в новый ответ для вашего вопроса. Запустите пример, доработайте под себя.

Comment: Строчку `Console.Write($"{new string('▓', progress)}{new string('░', Length - progress)}");` видите в ответе? Это и есть ответ на вопрос _Что я не так делаю?_ Вы рисуете в консоли только пробелы. Ровно 150 пробелов за все время работы программы, по 3 пробела 50 раз.

Comment: @aepot Обновил вопрос, теперь описал ещё проблемы

Comment: `Почему не отображается ]` - потому что вы нигде ее не выводите. Остальное не понял, вы не указали, что хотите получить, и почему у вас 3 цвета в прогрессе. Запустил код, еще больше запутался. Я вам вроде рабочее решение дал, вы его просто сломали и всё. `Thread.Sleep(100);` - а это зачем?

Comment: @aepot - я использовал три цвета для реалистичности, мне так лучше смотрится чем 2 цвета) , Sleep использовал для того чтобы видеть анимацию , да и чтобы юзер мог подумать что рил что-то грузится)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое хотели?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Progressbar();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Progressbar()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
        var posY = Console.CursorTop;
        string template = " Loading: ";
        Console.WriteLine(template);
        ConsoleProgressBar bar = new ConsoleProgressBar(template.Length, posY, 50);
        long previous = -1;
        long total = 1000000000;
        for (long i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            long progress = i * 100 / total;
            if (progress != previous)
            {
                bar.ShowProgress((int)progress);
                previous = progress;
            }
        }

        bar.ShowProgress(100);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}

public class ConsoleProgressBar
{
    public int Left { get; }
    public int Top { get; }
    public int Length { get; }

    public ConsoleProgressBar(int left, int top, int length)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Length = length;
    }

    public void ShowProgress(int progress)
    {
        if (progress > 100 || progress < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid progress value, must be between 0 and 100 but actual {progress}.");
        int p = progress * Length / 100;
        (int left, int top) = Console.GetCursorPosition();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
        Console.Write($"[{new string('█', p / 2)}" +
            new string('▓', p / 2 + p % 2) +
            $"{new string('░', Length - p)}] {progress}%");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(left, top);
    }
}
```

Переделал на задание прогресса в процентах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]